# Solving $\sin x + 2 \cos x=A\cos (x-x_0)$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

A question extracted from an university entrance exam:

> Real numbers $A$ and $x_0$ are given, with $A>0$, such that
>
> $\sin x + 2 \cos x=A\cos (x-x_0)$
>
> for all $x\in\mathbb R$. The value of $A$ is:
>
> a. $\sqrt 2$
>   b. $\sqrt 3$
>   c. $\sqrt 5$
>   d. $2\sqrt 2$
>   e. $2\sqrt 3$

There are some unofficial solutions to the above question, all similar to one another. One of those:

> Let $\theta$ be the acute angle of the following right triangle, as pointed, such that $\sin \theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$ and $\cos \theta=\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}$
>
> [image: triangle]
>
> Since $\sin x + 2 \cos x=A\cos (x-x_0)\iff $   $ \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\sin x + \frac{2}{\sqrt 5}\cos x=\frac{A}{\sqrt 5}\cos (x-x_0)\iff$   $\cos x\cos \theta+ \sin x \sin \theta=\frac{A}{\sqrt 5}\cos (x-x_0)\iff$
>   $\sqrt 5 \cos (x-\theta)=A\cos (x-x_0)$, and $A>0$, we have $A=\sqrt 5$

The question is: why is it assumed in the last step that $\theta =x_0$?

Comment: That statement may actually be false.Another way to do it (the standard way that always works) is to expand the LHS.$$ sinx+2cosx = A\cos(x-x_0)$$ $$sinx+2cosx = Acosxsin(x_0)+Asinxcos(x_0)$$ . i suppose you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is assumed equality holds for all $x$, you can plug in values for $x$; in particular, for $x=0$ and $x=\pi/2$, you get
$$
\begin{cases}
\sin 0+2\cos 0=A\cos(0-x_0) \\[4px]
\sin\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2\cos\dfrac{\pi}{2}=A\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x_0\right)
\end{cases}
$$
that becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
A\cos x_0=2 \\[4px]
A\sin x_0=1
\end{cases}
$$
Square and sum: $A^2(\cos^2x_0+\sin^2x_0)=2^2+1$.

---

Why can you deduce from $A>0$, $0\le x_0<2\pi$ and
$$
\sqrt{5}\cos(x-\theta)=A\cos (x-x_0)
$$
that $\theta=x_0$? Again, just plug in the values $x=0$ and $x=\pi/2$:
$$
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{5}\cos\theta=A\cos x_0 \\[4px]
\sqrt{5}\sin\theta=A\sin x_0
\end{cases}
$$
Square both equations and sum in order to get $A=\sqrt{5}$; then we get that $\theta$ and $x_0$ have the same sine and cosine, so being in $[0,2\pi)$ makes them equal.

Answer (score 1):

The real numbers $A\geq0$ and $x_0$ are not "given", but they can be **chosen** such that
$$\sin x +2\cos x=A\cos(x-x_0)\qquad\forall\ x\in{\mathbb R}\ .$$
Expanding the right hand side and comparing coefficients of $\cos x$, resp., $\sin x$ we obtain the following conditions for $A$ and $x_0$:
$$2=A\cos x_0,\qquad 1=A\sin x_0\ .\tag{1}$$
This implies $5=A^2(\cos^2 x_0+\sin^2 x_0)$, hence $A=\sqrt{5}$, and then
$\tan x_0={1\over2}$, hence $x_0=\arctan{1\over2}$, or $x_0=\arctan{1\over2}+\pi$, up to multiples of $2\pi$. Since $\cos x_0$ as well as $\sin x_0$ are $>0$ we may chose $x_0=\arctan{1\over2}$ in order to satisfy $(1)$.

Comment: I made a translation mistake with "given". It could be translated more precisely as "real numbers $A$ and $x_0$ are known to exist, with $A>0$, such that..."